# TFS Hide and show extension generated web work item work page

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am newbie in TFS extension.
My TFS extension contributed a custom work page on work item, on that page we show the data generated by our integrated app. All the data are stored in TFS.

I want to show or hide the tab if that work item has contains data.

Need help how to achieve this task if possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, show/hide a page base on condition is not supported in extension for now.